# Using WebDAV for Subversioning

Tags: svn, webdav

Does anyone know how to use subversioning with a WebDAV server?

I currently have a file hosting subscription which also provide me with a WebDAV access to the space. I would like to know if it's possible to connect Visual Studio (using AnkhSVN) to this WebDAV server and use it for versioning.

I tried it, and was able to connect to the server. But beyond that, it does not allow me to proceed further. Could someone share their ideas?

Comment: And do you really have a Subversion server installed behind the WebDAV server?

Comment: I don't know if a subversion server exists behind the WebDAV server.
But my file host supports versioning, would that help?
Also, is there any way to check if Subversion is running behind as you said?

Comment: You can check by simply setting any svn client to the url and let it show the repository or log.